# Move discussion to chat before reaching limit

Tags: discussion

on a recent question I had the feeling that a discussion should be continued in chat even before the link for automatically converting this to chat is shown. I've come accross this [posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467/how-can-i-move-a-discussion-to-chat-before-being-prompted) on meta.stackexchange. The comments suggest things like 'spam a bit' ... Also i've read about requests to make this possible but were not implemented yet.

How could I easily create a shortcut for chatting, when it is likely to need several comments to solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to their Stack Overflow user profile, yours is https://stackoverflow.com/users/3927116/shock-gone-wild , and then preface the domain with chat , so yours would be

> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3927116/shock-gone-wild

From there, a link is available

[image]

And you may start a chat room with the user

Comment: Let's hope he was in chat at least once already...

Comment: @Deduplicator - That has absolutely no bearing on this at all. Even new users of 1 reputation have a chat account - they just cannot enter rooms.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I wonder where I got the impression it wasn't so...

Comment: @Deduplicator IIRC you aren't listed on the chat users page until you've visited chat.

Comment: This user was created 9 seconds ago: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5724766/georgi-prusiyski (they cannot join chat so it isn't an option there)

Comment: However, this user who was created 9 days ago: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5700162/george-moralis and has never sent a message in chat, can be invited because they are above the 20 reputation threshold.

Comment: @TinyGiant - The "users" tab in chat is only a recent collection, not all time, and certainly not all available.

Comment: this was incredible helpful for me... thank you ;)

Comment: Does clicking the orange start-a-new-room-with-this-user automatically invite the user? Or do I have to send them the link, e.g. in comments?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone - It sends an invite notification, I am not sure if there is a delay.