# Create a chat room that has history from an existing solution

Tags: feature-request, chat

I often want to create a chat room to further discuss the issues surrounding an ordinary Stack Overflow solution that I have written

I have no problem creating a chat room and offering its URL to the OP, but I would like to be able to do manually what the system does automatically when it posts an invitation to discuss in chat

Do I simply have to wait for the automated prompt, or can I start a chat room with the necessary context?

The solution recommended [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313519/move-discussion-to-chat-before-reaching-limit) is to spam comments in order to get the prompt to appear. Not only is this a hacky solution, but it seems not to work now as there is a limit on the rate at which you can post comments, and spamming nonsense doesn't seem to trigger the prompt anyway

I'm elevating this to a feature request, as it is clear that it is something many people want but hasn't yet been implemented properly

The issue was raised [on meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing) in 2011, and raised the comment

> Is it possible to *beg* for this feature?

The nearest thing to a solution was

> **That isn't possible (yet) but it may be a good feature to think about adding in the future.**

Which prompted

> OK, the "yet" was 4 years ago – and "the future" is now. Still impossible? Whom to beg, where to nag for it?

It is now nearly five years since this feature request. Surely there could have been some movement in that time?

Comment: From the uber Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467/how-can-i-move-a-discussion-to-chat-before-being-prompted

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Move comments to chat"... on request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295219/move-comments-to-chat-on-request) and perhaps http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313519/move-discussion-to-chat-before-reaching-limit

Comment: @CodyGray: Thanks for the links, but there don't seem to be real solutions out there. The only way for non-moderators is to spam comments until the prompt comes up, which  isn't an answer I like, especially as it doesn't seem to *work*, as there is now a limit on the rate at which you can post comments, and I have managed to post twenty copies of `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` without getting the prompt